Angular application not accessible on browser deployed from minikube cluster
I deployed my own angular project on docker hub (one time the whole project and one time the dist folder after building the application), Both times logs showed successful deployment in the container.
Here is my config File for pod and service
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: audit-logger-frontend
  labels:
    app: logger-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logger-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logger-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logger-frontend
        image: huzaifi0604/logger-frontend:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: audit-logger-service
spec:
    selector:
        app: logger-frontend
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP  
      port: 4200
      targetPort: 4200
      nodePort: 31000

and this is the DockerFile for the project i deployed on Dockerhub
Docker File for Deploying angular Application 
# Use the official Node.js image
FROM node:18

# Updating the environment for the application
RUN apt-get update

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies with legacy peer deps
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

# Copy the rest of the application source code
COPY . .

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 4200

# Start the application
CMD ["npm", "start"]

I tried using NodePort and LoadBalacer both with and without nodePort key. Exposed port 4200 in docker file and set as target and containerPort in config files, got correct endpoints on service descriptions even got the service URL for accessing in browser, but in my browser the application is just not accessible.

These were my Logs for the pod created:

D:\K8is\Audit_Logger_Deployment>kubectl logs audit-logger-frontend-8595d84b97-tlkl8

> demoapp@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

- Building...

Initial chunk files | Names         |  Raw size
main.js             | main          |  94.68 kB |
polyfills.js        | polyfills     |  86.03 kB |
styles.css          | styles        |  70.77 kB |

                    | Initial total | 251.48 kB

Application bundle generation complete. [2.580 seconds]

Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
Re-optimizing dependencies because vite config has changed
  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/


and this was the service description

:\K8is\Audit_Logger_Deployment>kubectl describe service audit-logger-service
Name:                     audit-logger-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=logger-frontend
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.104.15.127
IPs:                      10.104.15.127
Port:                     <unset>  4200/TCP
TargetPort:               4200/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30000/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.5:4200
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>


Here are the Service URLs:

minikube service audit-logger-service
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |         NAME         | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | audit-logger-service |        4200| http://192.168.49.2:30000 |
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
* Starting tunnel for service audit-logger-service.
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|-----------------------|
| NAMESPACE |         NAME         | TARGET PORT |          URL          |
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|-----------------------|
| default   | audit-logger-service |             | http://127.0.0.1:7261 |
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|-----------------------|
* Opening service default/audit-logger-service in default browser...
! Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it.

Have any idea, what I might be doing incorrectly or might there be a network setting issue i m not aware of?

Can you please check if kubectl's port forwarding can be used to access the application. You can try the syntax kubectl port-forward svc/serviceName reachablePort:containerPort This will allow you to expose the service on localhost:<port number>. Once it is done, please try the command minikube service <service name>.

Let me know if the provided comment was helpful. I am happy to assist you in case of any further queries.

Well, it certainly might have worked if reaching ports or network connectivity between pods was the issue, which apparently was not. I discovered that my application was running normally on pod creation but as soon as i accessed it via an endpoint it tried connecting to the database, where the issue lies, since hard coded network endpoints and hostnames are not accessible outside the minikube containers and if i make them dynamic using config maps and secrets then the application won't build for pushing onto docker as an image since it does not know what those environmental variables are.
